# Python Element Tree Paths

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to write a python script to build an object from an XML Document but I am having some trouble understanding how paths work. Here is a sample of the XML Docs:

```
<args format="1.0">
<shaderType>
    <tag value="pattern"/>
</shaderType>
<help>
    Computes the facing ratio of the geometry : a simple dot product between
    the camera vector and the surface normal.
</help>
<page name="Parameters" open="True">
    <param name="faceForward"
        label="Face Forward"
        type="int"
        default="1"
        widget="checkbox">
        <tags>
            <tag value="__noconnection"/>
        </tags>
        <help>The facing ratio can be negative if the normal is pointing 
        away from the camera. This will flip the normal to always give a 
        positive result.</help>
    </param>
    <param name="invert"
        label="Invert"
        type="int"
        default="0"
        widget="checkbox">
        <tags>
            <tag value="__noconnection"/>
        </tags>
        <help>Inverts the facing ratio : black becomes white and 
        vice-versa.</help>
    </param>
    <param name="gamma"
        label="Gamma"
        type="float"
        default="1.0"
        widget="default">
        <tags>
            <tag value="float"/>
        </tags>
        <help>A simple gamma function to shape the facing ratio. A value of 1.0 is 
        neutral</help>
    </param>
    <param name="bumpNormal"
        label="Bump Normal"
        type="normal"
        widget="default">
        <tags>
            <tag value="normal"/>
        </tags>
        <help>If the surface is bump-mapped, input the bump normal here. If
        not connected, the node will use ths shading normal.</help>
    </param>
</page>

<output name="resultF">
    <tags>
        <tag value ="float"/>
    </tags>
</output>

<rfmdata nodeid="1053349"
         classification="rendernode/RenderMan/pattern"/>
```

Lets say I want to get the help statement for the object itself. I was using this:

```
    nodeText = tree.findtext('.//args/help')
    print nodeText
```

This however is returning None. Is the path I am using wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please confirm that the 'tree' object you're referring to is the root element of type Element and not an instance of type ElementTree ?

If it is of type ElementTree, please use the getroot() method to obtain the root element.

Basically, the following code snippet should get you the root element:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
args = parse('/path/to/file').getroot()
```

Subsequently, you can use the following to obtain each of the 'help' elements:

```
args.findall(".//help")
```

If you want just the 'help' element under the root object:

```
args.find("help")
```

If you want the text in the element:

```
print args.find("help").text
```

P.S: The XML snippet in your question above is missing the matching closing tag for 'args'

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
 nodeHelp = tree.xpath("/args/help")[0]
 print(nodeHelp.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I did give that a try but it is still returning None. I know the docs is reading in right because when I do a findall I get all the help elements.

Comment: @jspada Changed my answer.

Comment: Hey Tichodroma, Thanks for the assistance but that did not work as well because xpath was not supported by element tree. I did take what you did and used it to solve the problem. I know that it will always be the first element so I did a find all and selected the first element.